# How to link two differents cameras in wpf 3D

Tags: c#, wpf, helix-3d-toolkit

I have a project in wpf 3D / Helixtoolkit with two differents viewport, displaying two different but similar objects.

I have to implement a button that can "link" the two cameras of the two viewports. So when I'm changing the view in one, the other replicate the exact same transformation.

All in all, I want to activate the two viewport in the same time, not only by mouse overring one.

I'll take any lead.

EDIT : i found a pretty simple answer by simply copying one camera into the other into a CameraChanged event

```
private void viewport1_CameraChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        CameraHelper.Copy(viewport1.Camera, viewport2.Camera);
    }
```

I think it will do just fine

Comment: Hello Rémi, and welcome to StackOverflow! what have you tried so far, can we see some code?

Comment: @TimothyGroote thanks for your attention to this question. As said in the edit, I think I found a solution. Maybe I was aiming for something needlessly complex.